# How to connect callback with QPlainTextEdit change?

Tags: c++, qt, ros

I am listening to a topic and want to display and update the received value every time it changes.

This function creates the logging part of the GUI

```
  QGroupBox *Window::startLoggingGroup()
  {
      QGroupBox *groupBox = new QGroupBox(tr("Logging"));

      log_value = new QPlainTextEdit;
      log_value->setReadOnly(true);
      log_value->setPlaceholderText("Value will appear here \n");

      QHBoxLayout *hbox = new QHBoxLayout;
        hbox->addWidget(log_carrot);

      groupBox->setLayout(hbox);
      return groupBox;

  }
```

This is the code executed on every value changed.

```
void EFISWindow::callback_value(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& msg){
    QString qst = QString::number(msg.pose.position.z);
    log_value->setPlainText(qst);

}
```

It works at first, I can see the GUI and some values, but after several messages like the ones I show now it crashes:

> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextBlock' (Make
>   sure 'QTextBlock' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().) QObject:
>   Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
>   (Parent is QTextDocument(0x227e580), parent's thread is
>   QThread(0x1f9db50), current thread is QThread(0x7f4ae40011d0)

How can I solve this threading issue? Maybe using a signal-slot design? I don't really understand why this is not working.

Comment: Signals/slots isn't quite same as using callbacks, so you'd be better off not mixing the concepts (in writing or in thinking).

Comment: The error messages suggest (perhaps) that an instance of a `QObject` derived class with connections has been move to a new `QThread` but is still being accessed directly from the original thread.  You need to pinpoint where these message are coming from.  You might try installing a custom message handler using [qInstallMessageHandler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) and running under a debugger to get the call stack at the point the messages are emitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not access a GUI element from another thread.

> Maybe using a signal-slot design?

Yes, Your worker object should have a signal that you emit at some point and you should connect that signal to update the "log_value" value.

Comment: Now inside the callback I send a signal that activates a slot adding text, it is working fine.